# How can I measure block processing time on a given Ethereum client?

Tags: go-ethereum, testing, benchmark

I'm looking for a tool or library to measure block processing time on a given Ethereum client. My scenario would be to be able to compare block processing time to State size. The goal is to understand how state size impacts block processing time. The network I would set up would be of only one private node as I'm only interested in the client performances.

I know infura "versus" (https://github.com/INFURA/versus) but I'm not sure if it suits my need as it mostly measures the API response time for each request.

Does anyone know any tool/library/test suite that could help me?